# Is string check returns false

Tags: c#, string, validation, object

The following code:

```
protected bool IsStringAndNotNullAndEmpty(object value)
{
    var s = value as string;
    if (s != null)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Has the following `object` pass through:

```
"Relatively long option for testing"
```

This should happily be a `string`, however it's not it goes to the second `return` statement.

Any ideas why it may be doing this? I am stumped to be honest.

Comment: your string is not null and it's not empty, so it's returning false. Please debug before asking questions. Negate return in if

Comment: Why check for `null` at all? That is what `string.IsNullOrEmpty` does!

Comment: Your program comes to the string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) but as s in not null this method returns false...

Comment: Why have you called your method "Is string and it is not null and is empty" if you want it to return true when not empty? I think you need to rethink what your method needs to do and write code that does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To meet your method name, you need this:

```
protected bool IsStringAndNotNullAndEmpty(object value)
{
    var s = value as string;
    return s == string.Empty;
}
```

Changing its name to IsEmptyString(object value) would be clearer though.

It seems the OP actually wants a method that returns true for non-empty strings. So what is required is:

```
protected bool IsNonEmptyString(object value)
{
    var s = value as string;
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
}
```

Please take care with method names to make them say what the code actually does...

Answer (score 2):

You need to negate IsNullOrEmpty otherwise both will return false.

`return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);`

That is your method is called NotNullAndEmpty but you're simply return IsNullOrEmtpy!